# How can I get the cart item id after adding product to cart

Tags: magento-1.7, ajax, addtocart

I created a basic ajax addToCart function in the CartController and it works great. I just want the cart item id in this function.

I run:

```
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();
$this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Is there no way to output the cart item id from this?

Answer (score 1):

You could hook into two events:

sales_quote_item_save_before and sales_quote_item_save_after.

In the observer for save_before you could check if the item has id null, then set a flag. In save_after check if the flag is set, in that case set the item id in session and retrieve it in the controller and send it to the front end.

Comment: interesting. Is that going to hinder performance if I call an observer from a controller?

Comment: This did not work. I tried both events and ran $observer->getItem() with no data coming back.

Comment: You have to run $observer->getDataObject() to get the object from pre defined default model prefixed events.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it. Add an observer and hang its method on event **checkout_cart_product_add_after**.

Look at method: Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart::addProduct

```
/**
 * Add product to shopping cart (quote)
 *
 * @param   int|Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $productInfo
 * @param   mixed $requestInfo
 * @return  Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart
 */
public function addProduct($productInfo, $requestInfo=null)
{
    $product = $this->_getProduct($productInfo);
    $request = $this->_getProductRequest($requestInfo);

    $productId = $product->getId();
    ...
    if ($productId) {
        try {
            $result = $this->getQuote()->addProduct($product, $request);
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->getCheckoutSession()->setUseNotice(false);
            $result = $e->getMessage();
        }
        ...
    } else {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('The product does not exist.'));
    }

    Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_product_add_after', array('quote_item' => $result, 'product' => $product));
    $this->getCheckoutSession()->setLastAddedProductId($productId);
    return $this;
}
```

In observer's method you can get access to quote item and product.

Comment: So it looks like I could grab the item ID from $result then?

Comment: Yes, because result will entity of Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item.

Comment: Ok it makes sense that should have the data, but it's coming back empty. I'm really confused why this is such a challenge.

Comment: Then I can advice to debug it with help of xdebug - step-by-step. Maybe there is customization or something else. 

Also, you should try to get something like **$quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem()**, i.e. do not try to get quoteItem from $observer, only through getEvent().